# Clone/add sourcefroge project to git/egit

Tags: eclipse, git, sourceforge, egit

How to clone/add project from sourcefroge to git/egit,
here is for example project page:
[adudacity sourcefroge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/), now how to add this project to git.

Here is what I am trying, in source location I enter:
 **git://audacity.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/audacity/audacity** 
 
and in target i select some folder on PC,
but when I click next I get this error 
**fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only see SVN and CVS links and from

http://audacity.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb-index.cgi

you can see that it is an empty git repo.

Edit:

Like @adymitruk says, it looks like an ssh key issue for you, but it still looks like an empty repo ( I was able to clone )

Answer (score 0):

You don't have you public key set up properly. See here:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/SSH%20key%20fingerprints